# making Imageview displayed on fullScreen

Tags: android

I have 4 imageviews in an activity and I want that if the user clicks on any of the images .. the image should pop out and get displayed in full screen .. How can i possibly achieve this??

is using webviews a better option??

code:
    package com.integrated.mpr;

```
import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FinalShow extends Activity{



    ImageView iva;
    ImageView ivb;
    ImageView ivc;
    ImageView ivd;

    File folder = null;


    Model model = new Model();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.finalshow);



        iva = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iva);
        ivb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivb);
        ivc = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivc);
        ivd = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivd);



        String sdcardstate = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if(sdcardstate.contentEquals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){

            String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            folder = new File(filepath,model.s);//model.s contains the name of folder

            File fa = new File(folder,"bmp1.png");
            Bitmap bmpa = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fa.getAbsolutePath());
            iva.setImageBitmap(bmpa);

            File fb = new File(folder,"bmp2.png");
            Bitmap bmpb = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fb.getAbsolutePath());
            ivb.setImageBitmap(bmpb);


            File fc = new File(folder,"bmp3.png");
            Bitmap bmpc = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fc.getAbsolutePath());
            ivc.setImageBitmap(bmpc);


            File fd = new File(folder,"bmp4.png");
            Bitmap bmpd = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fd.getAbsolutePath());
            ivd.setImageBitmap(bmpd);

        }


    }



}
```

Comment: please provide more information or your code.

Comment: is the images is in your drawable folder?

Comment: no i am retreiving the images from the sd card

"sdcard/folder/bmp1.png"

Comment: please provide your main activity code, so i will change on this code and give u proper solution.

Comment: u can see i hav edited the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create one imageview(give full hight and width of the parent) which is invisible at the begining. On click of any image, set the image to to this new imageview and make it visible.

First make sure that the newly added imageview is covering full height and width. Better, you use relative layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/fullview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

in java code,

```
      firstImageView.setOnclickListener(new ClickListener());
      secondImageView.setOnclickListener(new ClickListener());
      thirdImageView.setOnclickListener(new ClickListener());
      fourthImageView.setOnclickListener(new ClickListener());



 class ClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()) {
                     case R.id.firstimage: // set image to fullimageview; break;
                      case R.id.secondimage:// set this image to fullimage break;
                    }

    }

}
```

Comment: onclick of any of the four imageview, make fifth imageview as visible in the code. use imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); and set the proper image to this view.

Comment: how to setup the onclick of any imageview?? Simply by onclicklistener .. just like buttons??

Comment: yes. give click listeners for imageview. wait i will update my answer with that

Comment: change the code according to your xml. logic i have given. :) after setting img to fullview, dont forget to make it visible.

Comment: Thanku it works .. but after the fullview image is displayed how to go back .. if i press the back button of emulator , it goes to the previous activity

Comment: thanks a lot raghu .. but now wat i am doing is .. creating 4 new activities for the full screen display of images .. and opening them by intent in the switch case of onclick .. but thats a edious slution isn't it??

Comment: @Kumar its not good solution kumar. Create 4 new activity is not a good idea. if you want to display it in new activity, then create one new activity. Then pass image path to intent extra, using intent.putExtra.

Comment: can u plz explain how to pass the imagepath to the new activity?? and wat will be the declarartion of the new activity?

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing make a new activity : After that on Image click call another activity in between you can add animation for pop up :

In new Activity display your image as you said : for passing value of image you can use Shared Preferences or Intent also : Good Luck